# How to link Zlib with Cmake

Tags: c, cmake, gzip, zlib

I am trying to link my file with the zlib libray but still get: undefined reference to `deflateInit_'.

I am currently using CLion, have downloaded the zLib file from the homepage and added it into the project. This is how my CmakeLists.txt looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10) project(GzipTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(ZLIB zlib-1.2.11)

add_executable(GzipTest main.cpp zlib-1.2.11/zlib.h)
```

And the code (Copying from the zpipe.c):

```
include "iostream"

include "zlib.h"

include "iostream"

define CHUNK 1639


FILE *fp;


int def(FILE *source, FILE *dest, int level){
    int ret, flush;
    unsigned have;
    z_stream strm;
    unsigned char in[CHUNK];
    unsigned char out[CHUNK];

    // Allocate Deflate state
    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;

    ret = deflateInit(&strm, level);
    if (ret != Z_OK){
        return ret;
    }

}


int main(){
    fp = fopen("inputFile.txt", "r");
    if (fp == nullptr){
        perror("Could not open data");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    def(fp, fp, 1); 
}
```

What could be missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you compiled zlib? Where is libzlib.so or similar?

Comment: You don't build with the zlib source file, or link with the zlib library.

Comment: How to compile zlib?

Comment: You have doanloaded a package, there is a README in it with the instructions on how to build it on all platforms. You can also directly get a prebuilt package.

Comment: Matthieu, the readme:  # To install libz.a, zconf.h and zlib.h in the system directories, type:
#
#   make install -fwin32/Makefile.gcc.

Answer (score 25):

You have to link against zlib.

If you used:

```
find_package(ZLIB)
```

Then you should have:

```
target_link_libraries(GzipTest ZLIB::ZLIB)
```

Also don't add the headers to your source files:

```
add_executable(GzipTest main.cpp)
```

Comment: Should i replace ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES} with something? I get : CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (target_link_library):
  Unknown CMake command "target_link_library".

Comment: That's assuming that you have the package built, and that you are setting the paths to find zlib for cmake properly. And yes, fixed a type, should be librarIES, not librarY.

Comment: @AKJ which version of cmake are you using?

Comment: I am really a noob at this. Can you please instruct me on what to do?

Comment: in the cmake-gui (or ccmake on Linux, but in that case, you should already have a zlib package with the system), you need to fill the path to zlib as the errors that find_package indicates.

Comment: Philipp, i am using Cmake 3.10.2

Comment: @AKJ You need to use `target_link_libraries`, not `target_link_library` (note the plural form).

Comment: @Michael, i have already solved the issue. It is easier once one has mastered CMake.

Answer (score 7):

It seems this old post is getting a lot of traction.
The solutions to linking zlib with CMake are either:

1. To download zlib, if on Linux with

   ```
    sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
   ```

   and then following what Matthieu proprosed.
2. Or download zlib like in 1 and do:

   ```
    add_executable(my_executable main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(my_executable z)
   ```
3. Or just download zlib from their homepage: https://zlib.net/, then save it in a 'deps' folder. Modify the CMakeList in the zlib folder with

   ```
    set(ZLIB_DEPS_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} PARENT_SCOPE)
   ```

   and in the main CMakeList, do

   ```
    add_executable(my_executable main.cpp)
    add_subdirectory(deps)
    include_directories(my_executable ${ZLIB_DEPS_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(my_executable zlib)
   ```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` should be highlighted, it's important.

Comment: In `3.`, where is `ZLIB_DEPS` defined?

Comment: `ZLIB_DEPS` is not defined anywhere. It is being assigned. Like x = 2, where x is the `ZLIB_DEPS_DIR` and CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR is 2.

Comment: I understand, but that wasn't the question. The actual ZLIB_DEPS variable in the above is never set, and assumed to be an artifact of the subdirectory addition? The question wasn't about ZLIB_DEPS_DIR ; it was about ZLIB_DEPS. Or is the latter just wrong and it was *supposed* to be ZLIB_DEPS_DIR in *all* occurrences in (3) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig you are right. I made a mistake. ZLIB_DEPS and ZLIB_DEPS_DIR should be the same variables.